# Access a specific ABAddressbook Group

Tags: ios, addressbook, abaddressbook

I am using

```
NSMutableArray *people = [[[(NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook) autorelease] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

to access the Addressbook.
Now I want to access a specific Addressbook Group from an Exchange Server. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do not something like this.

```
ABRecordRef exchange = ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID(addressBook, kABSourceTypeExchange);
CFArrayRef groups = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroupsInSource(addressBook, exchange);

CFArrayRef officePersonnel;
for (ABRecordRef group in (NSArray *)groups) {
    CFStringRef groupName = ABRecordCopyValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty, NULL);
    if ( CFStringFind(groupName, CFSTR("Office"), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive) != kCFNotFound ) {
        officePersonnel = ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers(group);
    }
    CFRelease(groupName);
}

CFRelease(groups);

// Use and later release `officePersonnel`
```